# Data saved in the database is missing the @Embeddable customer's address

Tags: reference, embeddable

My customer has, among other data, the address. The address consists of the following data:

Street and number
ZIP code
City
Country

I create the class CustomerAddress, which looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomerAddress {
    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;
    @Column(name = "zipCode")
    private String zipCode;
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    public CustomerAddress(String street, String zipCode, String city, String country) {
        this.street = street;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public CustomerAddress() {
    }
    public String getStreet() { return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) { this.street = street;
    }
    public String getZipCode() {return zipCode;
    }
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
    public String getCity() { return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) { this.city = city;
    }
    public String getCountry() { return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) { this.country = country;
    }
}
```

My Customer Repository class looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    long countById(Long id);
}
```

I am writing the test where my customer is being saved in the database:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Rollback(false)
public class CustomerRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    public void testAddNewCustomer() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setUserLoginName("Endera_Hifhra");
        customer.setUserEmail("Endera_Hifhra@gmail.com");
        customer.setUserPassword("querty1234");
        customer.setCustomerName("Endera");
        customer.setCustomerSurname("Hifhra");
        customer.setRole(Role.CUSTOMER);
        LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(1990, 9, 14);
        customer.setCustomerBirthDate(Date.valueOf(birthDate).toLocalDate());

        CustomerAddress address = new CustomerAddress();
        address.setCity("Musterstadt");
        address.setCountry("Musterland");
        address.setStreet("Feuer Str. 21");
        address.setZipCode("81546");

        customer.setCustomerAddress(address);

        Customer savedCustomer = customerRepository.save(customer);

        Assertions.assertThat(savedCustomer.getId()).isNotNull();
     
    } 
}
```

Why are all the data except the address being written to the database?

I tryed to add Constructor, but it doesn't work.